# Azure Mobile Services: Custom Authentication using Java script backend?

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-mobile-services

Anyone please suggest me tutorial or referrence to 
implement custom Authentication using Java script backend in windows azure mobile service.

I had gone through the link:

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-get-started-custom-authentication

it has only .Net backend. Would appreciate if anyone has implemented or has idea on this could share code or highlight on the implementation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question; it's more like a documentation question. And there's an entire portal filled with mobile services documentation, [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/mobile-services/). Just select JavaScript as the backend, and choose one of the tutorials (one of which is [this one](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-windows-store-dotnet-call-custom-api/)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this post (and the ones linked off from it): http://chrisrisner.com/Custom-Authentication-with-Azure-Mobile-Services-and-LensRocket.  Essentially you need to create a Login and a Register method (with the suggestion to do so using Custom APIs).  Inside of these you'll generate your own JWT for authenticated users.

Comment: the issue with the question is that it requests a reference link (which isn't a programming question). Having said that: Since you provided an answer, it would be much better to at least illustrate some of what the link is referring to. If that link disappears, so does the reference to your answer.